# How do I do an IF statement on the same cell on multiple sheets, then display the sum of the true values in another sheet?

Tags: excel

I have 7 sheets (Date 1-7) which all have a letter value in cell C24 and a monetary value in D24, I want to check if this value is A for all 7 sheets. See [image: here].

On an 8th sheet I want to display the total for all sheets but I only want to add the value of D24 where the value of C24 was equal to A. See [image: here].

I can check the value of one sheet by using the following IF Statement:

> =IF('Date 1'!C24="A",'Date 1'!D24,"0")

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set up a column of values with the names of the sheets that you want to include, you will see below that I have put them in column D of my worksheet; i.e.

Date 1

Date 2

...

Date 7

Then use the following excel formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&D2:D8&"'!C24"), "A",INDIRECT("'"&D2:D8&"'!D24")))
```

Comment: This: `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'Date "& {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} &"'!C24"),"A",INDIRECT("'Date "& {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} &"'!D24")))` will do it without the need of a helper column.

Comment: Impressed with that! I guess you could shorten it by using row(1:7) instead of the list in curly brackets?

Comment: Thanks so much to all of you, also @TomSharpe it doesn't seem to work if I use 1:7

Comment: It seemed fine when I tested it with this formula =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'Date "&ROW(1:7)  &"'!C24"),"A",INDIRECT("'Date "&ROW(1:7)  &"'!D24")))

Answer (score 1):

Another solution might be to use SUMIF on each sheet (Date 1 - Date 7) to get the total Shift A downtime on each. Then SUM those on Sheet 8.

on sheets 1 - 7
=SUMIF(C24:C25,C24,D24:D25)

on sheet 8
=SUM('Date 1:Date 7'!D26) assuming the formula above is in D26 on each sheet.

for some reason Excel doesn't let you use SUMIF across sheets.

Comment: Yes SUMIF isn't included on the list here unfortunately https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-a-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-c906f8b4-c648-4aa0-8063-65d38d03370f Also it would be =SUM('Date 1:Date 7'!D26) of course for 7 sheets

Comment: Good catch Tom. Thanks!