# Total values across multiple tabs in Excel using formula

Tags: excel, tabs, addition, sumifs

In the images below, I have a Master sheet that I would like to total the values from year-to-year (2015, 2014, 2013, etc.) for each letter (A, B, C, D).

[image: Master Tab]

[image: 2015 Tab]

[image: 2014 Tab]

Please keep in mind that some Letters (A, B, C, D) may not always be included in the yearly sheets. For example, "A" is not included in 2013. Therefore, "B" would be in cell B2 of the 2013 tab.

As of now, all I have summed up in the Master Tab is from the 2015 tab using a SUMIF function (e.g., `=SUMIF('2015'!A2:A5, "A",'2015'!B2:B5)`).

I've been looking for / trying formulas that will add in the other year tabs (2014, 2013, etc), but nothing seems to be working.

Any ideas?

Comment: our example shows that *A-Value1* is always in cell **B2** of each yearly sheet...is this true for all yearly sheets ??

Comment: It's not always the case for all yearly sheets because "A" might not be in 2013.

Comment: Have a look at this recent question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615382/how-do-i-do-an-if-statement-on-the-same-cell-on-multiple-sheets-then-display-th/34624241#comment57060256_34624241

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually was able to answer my own question and this formula is what I am looking for. It does, however, require adding the yearly sheet names on the Master tab (as shown below in cells `F1:F4`)

[image: Answer - Master Tab]